# How can I call npm module from PHP class

Tags: javascript, php

I found a javascript plugin to convert HTML to markdown here https://github.com/domchristie/to-markdown.

I'm using Laravel 5. Let's say a user post an HTML string and I take the request from my PHP class. Here's my controller:

```
<?php
    class TheController extends Controller
    {
        ...
        public function index()
        {
            $html_text = Request::input('html_text');
            // Convert $html_text to $markdown
        }
    }
?>
```

If I were in a javascript file I could've called the function like this:

```
var toMarkdown = require('to-markdown');
toMarkdown('<h1>Hello world!</h1>');
```

How do I convert `$html_text` to `$markdown` without converting it to a text file and read it, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use a npm package for that, there are plenty php packages to do this. You can find a lot of packages compatible with Laravel on [packalyst](http://packalyst.com/).

For example:
http://packalyst.com/packages/package/alfredo-ramos/parsedown-extra-laravel